# HTML5 Audio Tag volume-control

Tags: html, audio, volume

Is it possible for the audio Tag to only display the volume settings and not the rest?

Hope you can help me with that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the answer is no because the browser will handle your file and each browser will have a differente player. As the `<audio>` tag does not provide that much option in the html 5 there's no chance it will be possible without using broswer special option.

**Edit 1:**
What you can do is using js to send control to your file and do not display your html audio file.
See the demo [here](http://demo.codesamplez.com/javascript/audio)

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what i was looking for. Really easy to use and works just like i want it! Thanks!

Comment: @RenokK glad you like that.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('audio').currentTime = 0;
```

What this does is it sets the playtime back to zero seconds.

Among the many functions and properties of this tag you can use .play(), .pause(), .ended, .paused, and .duration in your javascript to manipulate it. And you can even set the .currentTime property to a number within the range of your clip's playback duration (in seconds) to start midway through the clip if you wanted.